# Can a frame be both parent_id and child_id?

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, ros-kinetic, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using odom as parent_id for base_link and child_frame_id for map tf in the respective launch files. Will it cause any issues in my tf tree?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327175/can-a-frame-be-both-parent_id-and-child_id?/) by [sajal](https://answers.ros.org/users/41875/sajal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-06-27**:
As long as your overall TF tree doesn't have any loops or multiple roots then this shouldn't be a problem at all.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-27**:
I would go even further: how would we ever create tree structures (or any linked structures) if frames can't be both parent and child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, it won't cause any issues, that is exactly how hierarchy trees work.

Me myself am a father because I have children, but at the same time I am a child because I have a father.

Same for the example you describe.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0